# Открытие линков в webview

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

Добавил в приложение webview.
Но при переходе по линкам, открывается в браузере.

```
    <android.webkit.WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:id="@+id/webView" />
```

и

```
        webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        //Load URL in txtURL in WebView.  
        webView.LoadUrl("https://google.com/");
```

Мне нужно что бы линки открывались внутри webview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно назначить `WebViewClient`.
В данном случае достаточно стандартного:

```
    webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
    webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    //Load URL in txtURL in WebView.  
    webView.LoadUrl("https://google.com/");
```